# Floor inequality in proof

Tags: functions, inequality, proof-explanation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, step-function

[image: Problem statement]

I am currently trying to understand the proof that
$[-x] = -[x]-1$ if $x$ is not an integer (solutions for $b$.)

where $[x]$ is the floor function.

Can somebody explain me how he went from
$$-n-1 < -x < n$$
to
$$[-x] = -n - 1 = -[x]-1$$
in the solutions for $b$.

Comment: Your hang-up (I think) is that the floor function on a positive number will bring the absolute value (ie $|x|$) closer to $0$, whereas the floor of a negative value will further the absolute distance from $0$. So, when I floor a positive number and negate it after, I will still have to subtract the additional $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $-n-1<-x<-n$, the number $-n-1$ is the greatest integer less or equal $-x$ (it is less than $-x$ but the next integer, namely $(-n-1)+1=-n$ is greater).

Therefore $[-x]=-n-1$. Since $[x]=n$, we get $[-x]=-n-1=-[x]-1$.

Comment: Thanks. This wording helped.

Comment: The reason why I couldnt understand it was because I wasnt fully aware of that "-n-1" is just "-x" rounded down. Thank you!

Comment: Floor (as the name suggest) is always rounding down, so $[\pi]=3$ but $[-\pi]=-4$.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof that may help:

Let $x = a + \epsilon$ where $a \in \Bbb Z, \epsilon \in (-1,1)$. This is a way to formulate $x$ in terms of its integer and decimal component.

Then $[x]$ = $a + [\epsilon]$ (try to convince yourself of this) and $[-x] = -a + [-\epsilon]$.

If $\epsilon = 0$ (ie $x$ is an integer and, thus,  $[\epsilon] = 0$), then the $[-x] = -[x]$ equality should be obvious.

Suppose $\epsilon \gt 0$, then we have $[x] = a + 0 = a$ and $[-x] = -a + (-1)$. Then we have $[-x] = [x] - 1$.

If $\epsilon \lt 0$, then we have $[x] = a - 1$ and $ [-x] = -a + 0$. Again, $[-x] = -[x] -1$.

Comment: Thank you! Noted.